# File not sending via cron job (PHP script)

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, email-attachments

I'm trying to create a cron job that sends an email with a file attachment once a day.

I'm using a simple PHP script to test this and **it works fine when I go to the URL and run it**. However, when running it via the cron job, the email is sent but not the file attachment.

### Here's my PHP script

**Please note I've changed info to protect my client, so I use a real email, not `test@example.com` just so you don't think that's why it's not working.**

```
<?php 
 
// Recipient 
$to = 'test@example.com'; 
 
// Sender 
$from = 'noreply@example.com'; 
$fromName = 'Server'; 
 
// Email subject 
$subject = 'Test Subject';  
 
// Attachment file 
$file = "../test/file.csv";
 
// Email body content 
$htmlContent = ' 
    <h3>Test Email</h3> 
    <p>Please find the attached file.</p> 
'; 
 
// Header for sender info 
$headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">"; 
 
// Boundary  
$semi_rand = md5(time());  
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  
 
// Headers for attachment  
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
 
// Multipart boundary  
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";  
 
// Preparing attachment 
if(!empty($file) > 0){ 
    if(is_file($file)){ 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
        $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb"); 
        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file)); 
 
        @fclose($fp); 
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .  
        "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .  
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n"; 
    } 
} 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--"; 
$returnpath = "-f" . $from; 
 
// Send email 
$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);  
 
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful if you posted your CRON command, but I'm going to guess that it begins with something like :

```
php path/to/your/script.php
```

If so I think the problem is with this line:

```
$file = "../test/file.csv";
```

The path to the file is relative. Likely CRON isn't operating from the directory that the script exists in so it's trying to find the file from a directory above it's current working directory, where it doesn't exist.

Option 1: change the path to an absolute.

Option 2: If your PHP script exists in the web directory you could change the CRON command to use [WGET](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) instead, eg.

```
wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null 'https://example.com/yourScript.php'
```

Comment: Excellent, you're welcome. I think if you upvote/mark the answer as useful I might get some kudos points..!